# How can i create sub directories within a directory?

Tags: shell, unix, zsh, subdirectory, directory-structure

I am trying to make a photo organizer with a zsh shell script. But i am having trouble creating sub directories within each main directory(based on date). Currently the script starts from a folder i created and gets one argument(the file it needs to edit, hence the first cd $1). Secondly, i do some name changing which is irrelevant for my question. Next i create a directory for each date and move the photo to the correct directory.

The issue is, i want to loop through each date folder and make 2 new sub directories(jpg and raw). But when i run the code i get an error that there is no such file or directory..

Here is my current script:

```
#!/bin/zsh.
cd $1
for i in *.JPG;
do
        mv $i $(basename $i .JPG).jpg;
done
        
for i in *;
do
       d=$(date -r "$i" +%d-%m-%Y)
       mkdir -p "$d"
       mv -- "$i" "$d/";
done
for d in *;
do
        cd $d
        for i in *.jpg;
        do
                mkdir -p "jpg"
                mv -- "$i" "jpg";
        done

        for i in *.NEF;
        do
                mkdir -p "raw"
                mv -- "$i" "raw";
        done
done
```

If anyone knows where i made a mistake that would be really helpfull since i have no clue what goes wrong and there is no debugger in nano as far as i know.

Comment: Add `cd -` before the very last `done`, or use full paths: `for i in "$PWD"/*/; do cd ...`. That will cause this error. Quote all variables and command substitutions, and it might work. Also, put the last two `mkdir`s below `cd "$d"`, outside the inner loops - they only need to run once per sub directory.

Comment: What is the period doing at the end of the #!-line?